# Automomatic typographical error correction

Tags: text-mining, data-cleaning

Does anyone know where I might be able to find a list of the most common typing errors and their corrections? This is separate from more complicated considerations concerning general spelling checking (which can have very many candidates in relation to the correct spelling of the word in question); rather I am looking for a similar list as used by Microsoft Word (for instance correcting

> teh

with

> the

or

> becaise

with

> because

Not only can the manner in which these sort of errors are fixed be hard-coded, their frequent occurrence in text provides significant dividends in textual mining (provided that such a list of errors and corrections can be obtained, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I will reference two sources:

- Wikipedia has its own lists: [Lists of common misspellings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Lists_of_common_misspellings)
- [Aspell](http://aspell.net/) is certainly a place to visit. You can find a list of misspellings and corrections [here](http://aspell.net/test/common-all/batch0.tab).

Still, it is a good idea to think of using a spell checker, such as Aspell, since it gives you the ability to deal with no-so-common misspellings (of course, at the cost of false positives). A good starting point is Peter Norvig's [essay](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) on creating a spelling corrector.